# Newer version of JRE doesn't load soundbank but older version does

Tags: audio, java, midi, javax.sound.midi

I have the following code that tries to load a soundbank. I've tested the code on Windows 7 with JRE 1.6.03 and 1.6.43. The old version of the JRE (1.6.03) works fine but the new version throws an exception. What's going on?

```
public Main() {
    try {
        Synthesizer synth = MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
        synth.open();
        BufferedInputStream soundBankStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                        "soundbank.gm"));
        synth.loadAllInstruments(MidiSystem.getSoundbank(soundBankStream));
    } catch (MidiUnavailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidMidiDataException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

.

```
F:\>java -version
java version "1.6.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_03-b05)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.6.0_03-b05, mixed mode)

F:\>java -jar Test2.jar

F:\>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -version
java version "1.6.0_43"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_43-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)

F:\>"C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -jar Test2.jar
javax.sound.midi.InvalidMidiDataException: cannot get soundbank from stream
        at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSoundbank(Unknown Source)
        at com.gulshansingh.test.Main.<init>(Main.java:24)
        at com.gulshansingh.test.Main.main(Main.java:14)
```

You can download the soundbanks from here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/soundbanks-135798.html

Comment: I'm just curious, have you tried Java 1.7?

Comment: Search the [bug DB](http://bugs.sun.com/). If nothing present, raise a new one.

Comment: @Telthien Same error in 1.7

Comment: I'm going with Andrew's suggestion, then.

Answer (score 0):

Copy-Paste from [Java Sound API: Soundbanks](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/soundbanks-135798.html) page

> Java Sound API
>
> This page provides different soundbanks which you can download and use
> with Java Sound. Soundbanks are necessary for correct operation of the
> internal software synthesizer that ships with Java Sound. By default,
> the Windows version of the J2RE does not ship with a soundbank, so you
> need to manually install one to use Java Sound's MIDI engine. Java
> Sound has a fallback mechanism that uses a hardware MIDI port if no
> soundbank is available, but it prevents reliable and consistent MIDI
> playback, so installation of a soundbank is recommended for Java
> Sound.

As you can see, Java Sound API need installation, so if you have installed a newer JDK, you have to [redo the installation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/soundbanks-135798.html#install).

A bug seem to be near your problem: [4887447](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4887447), a workaround exists but not if the banksound is in a JAR

Comment: I load the soundbank.gm file as a resource, so I don't need to install it separately.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same problem, and from what I have found, the latest versions of java (1.7+), the GM soundbanks are no longer supported

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html#incompatibilities

> The software synthesizer implementation in the Java Sound package has been replaced with an open sourced version. Due to the replacement, the following features were dropped:
>   GM soundbank support,
>   RMF file playback support,
>   OSS (Open Sound System) support on the Linux platform.
>   The new synthesizer implementation supports soundbanks in DLS and SoundFont (SF2) formats.

As it says, it supports the DLS and SF2 Soundbank formats (which I tried with what you were doing and it worked). Have a look around on the internet for these files such as here:
http://www.ronimusic.com/smp_ios_dls_files.htm